# Why is my CSRF token failing in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-csrf

I've provided CSRF in `views.py` and included `csrf_token` in templates, but still search is not working due to “csrf_token failure”.

My `views.py` code is:

```
args = {}
args.update(csrf(request))
args['articles']= Article.objects.all()
args['lang'] = language
args['session_language']=session_language
return render_to_response('articles.html', args)
```

and template code is

```html
<h3>Search</h3>
{% csrf_token %}
<input type='text' id='search' name='search' />
```

Comment: We will probably need to see more code and the stacktrace.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Where is your form and how do you submit it?

Comment: Is the `csrf_token` inside a `form` tag? Is this a regular HTML `form` submit (are you using some kind of AJAX)?

Comment: yes i am using AJAX so,  csrf_token is not inside an HTML form

Comment: Where is your AJAX post code?

Comment: take a look here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

Comment: my relevant  ajax code is:    $.ajax ( {
   type: "POST",
   url: "/articles/search/",
   data: {
    'search_text' : $('#search').val(),
    'csrfmiddlewaretokken': $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretokken]").val()
   },
   success: searchSuccess,
   datatype: 'html'
   
  });   @Selcuk

Answer (score 0):

The `csrf_token` is just the string that is required, you need to do something with it. For starters, capturing it within your template in script takes will mean javascript is "aware" of it.

```
{# Place this somewhere in your template #}
<script type="text/javascript">
    var csrf_token = "{{ csrf_token }}";
</script>
```

After this, how you submit the AJAX request is up to you, but you can now use this as part of your POST submission.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass the csrf token value in every POST request made.